# Restriction of a Haar measure

Tags: harmonic-analysis, haar-measure

Let G be a locally compact topological group with Haar measure $d_G$, H be a compact subgroup of G with normalized Haar measure $d_H$ and N **be the smallest normal subgroup of G containing of H** with Haar measure $d_N$.

First question: Is there any relation between the Haar measures $d_G,d_H$ and $d_N$?

Second question: Can we write $d_G|_H=d_H$?

Third question: Can we write $d_H(H)=d_N(N)$?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Frequently $H$ would have measure zero in $G$, so the restriction of $d_G$ to $H$ would yield the zero measure.  For instance, $SO(n)$ as a subgroup of $GL(n)$.  I think the construction you're looking for is not restriction but [disintegration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem).

Comment: For the third question, assuming $N$ is compact, how do you normalize $d_N$?  If $d_N$ is normalized Haar measure then the statement $d_H(H)=d_N(N)$ is trivial since they are both 1 by definition.

Comment: It could also happen that $N$ is not compact.  For instance, take $G = GL(n)$ and $H = O(n)$.  Then $d_N(N)=\infty \ne d_H(H)$.

Comment: Tank you very much for your useful guidance.